# How to use NeroAacEnc in Terminal on Mountain Lion

Tags: codec, wine, aac

How can I encode audio using the amazing [NeroAacEnc](http://www.nero.com/eng/downloads-nerodigital-nero-aac-codec.php)? Is there a way to compile it for Mac OS or is Wine the only solution?

I am trying to combine it with x264 through ffmpeg for HD video transcoding.

Comment: Do you have the source code, or how'd you compile it?

Comment: I downloaded it off their website, and it came as linux and win32 versions...

Answer (score 1):

You can either use it under wine, or use qaac (Apple's Quicktime AAC encoder), which is broadly considered as good - and sometimes even better than - neroAacEnc.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way to use it with Wine. The quality of this codec compared to FAAC is is much better. Great!

1. Install Wine via macports following the advise given in [this tutorial](http://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/wine-mac/)
   `sudo port install wine` as well as the other instructions from the tutorial
2. Make sure all dependencies are installed as well as an X server (Xquartz or xorg-server via macports)
3. Place the NeroAACEncoder win32-folder with its contents somewhere on your mac, preferably in the `~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/` folder.
4. Now run any NeroAACEnc command through Wine:

   `wine start neroAacEnc.exe -q 0.85 -if INPUT.wav -of OUTPUT.mp4`